# Centering the tile text on promoted links

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, css, promoted-links

I need to center align the text on the tiles of promoted links, which it does, but not consistently to all the tiles in all the lines when I use the CSS below. What am I missing?

```
<style>
.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextSmallCollapsed,
.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed,
.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextSmallExpanded,
.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumExpanded 
{text-align:center}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you add screenshot to have clear understanding of your ask ?

Answer (score 2):

One would guess that `text-align: center` itself would do the job, but because the promoted links have a modified `display`-attribute, they no longer conform to `display: block`, which takes all the available space and respects the styling of `center`. However, by changing back to `display: block`, the functionality still works so it's alright to add it to the code.

The following does the job:

```
.ms-tileview-tile-titleMedium,
.ms-tileview-tile-titleMediumCollapsed,
.ms-tileview-tile-titleMediumExpanded,
.ms-tileview-tile-titleSmall,
.ms-tileview-tile-titleSmallCollapsed,
.ms-tileview-tile-titleSmallExpanded,
.ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you only want to apply the changes to the body text, you need to have `.ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium` on the selected elements, and vice versa.

[image]